# Linker error when cross compiling for raspberry pi

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, rusqlite

I try to cross-compile a simple rust program with sqlite on Linux for raspberry pi:

Cargo.toml

```
...

[dependencies]
rusqlite = { version = "0.26.3", features = ["bundled"] }
```

.cargo/config

```
[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "/opt/crosspi/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```

When trying to build with `cargo build --release --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` rust bails out with a linker error which basically says:

```
error: linking with `/opt/crosspi/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit status: 1

...

  = note: /home/hannenz/pidev/projects/kiddyblaster/webui-rust/target/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/deps/liblibsqlite3_sys-950993cbbcc1e3eb.rlib(sqlite3.o):(.data.rel.aSyscall+0x58): undefined reference to `fcntl64'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(The `...` is the full gcc command line, i can post the whole output if relevant)

Without rusqlite cross-compiling works and compiling for the host target is working as well. I also tried the `sqlite` crate instead of `rusqlite`, but that produces the exact same linker error.

Would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction what's goiong wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Cross compiling can be a bit tricky, luckily the cross crate (https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) makes it simple. Follow these steps:

- Install cargo cross: `cargo install cross`
- Create a file called `Cross.toml` in the root directory (where Cargo.toml is) with this content

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
image = "my-custom-cross"
```

- Create a Dockerfile with this content

```
FROM rustembedded/cross:aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes libsqlite3-dev:arm64
```

- Build the docker container: `docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t my-custom-cross --load .`
- Build your program: `cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release`

Now you have your binary compiled at `target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release` directory

## A bit of explanation

The project `cross-rs` prepared all the environment and put it in a docker container. We created our own container based on this (`FROM rustembedded/cross:aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`) and we added the extra libraries we need, in this case the dev sqlite3 (`apt-get install --assume-yes libsqlite3-dev:arm64`).

Once our docker container is ready, we configured `cross` to use this container by using the file `Cross.toml`.

Depending on your raspberry and the operating system you use in your raspberry, you may need to use other arquitecture. In this case just change `aarch64` by yours. In my case I'm using rpi3 64 bit. In case you are using 32 bit or an older board, try something like `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` or go to the "Supported targets" section in the cross documentation https://github.com/cross-rs/cross.

Dont forget to configure `Cross.toml` and the Dockerfile to use your target architecture!